# Move selected list item right with overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a sidebar that I created in bootstrap, but I can't figure out how to move a selected item to right, and have it flow over the nav div. I tried increasing z-index.

Maybe I should use flexbox instead. Then I could add a cell in front and next to the menu item. Then when the item is selected, I could set width on the first cell, and a width of 0 to the last cell. The other (unselected) items could have a width on the last cell. This way I suppose I could create visually the same thing.

Anyways, suggestions are more than welcome.

HTML:

```
<nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-faded sidebar vdl-sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-klass="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" href="#">
        Item 11
        <span class="badge badge-pill pull-right badge-success">on</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item selected">
      <a class="nav-link d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        Item 13
        <span class="badge badge-pill pull-right badge-success">on</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" href="#">
        Item 14
        <span class="badge badge-pill pull-right badge-success">on</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/*
     * Sidebar
     */

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* Sidebar navigation */

.sidebar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.sidebar .nav {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sidebar .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

@media (pointer: fine) {
    nav.vdl-sidebar a.nav-link:hover {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

.sidebar .nav-item+.nav-item {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.sidebar .nav-item+.nav-item.selected {
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.sidebar .nav-link {
    border-radius: 0;
}

nav.vdl-sidebar a.nav-link.active {
    background-color: green;
}

nav.vdl-sidebar a.nav-link:not(.active) {
    color: green;
}

.badge-pill {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/09ogyde4/

Comment: Making the ul position fixed will do, i hope  **.sidebar .nav {position:fixed; 
}**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x: visible;` and `overflow-y: visible;` on a `.sidebar` element, or just remove this lines.